# Why am I getting this error during Realm migration?: 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid value for property'

Tags: swift, realm

I am doing a migration, in Realm, to convert a string to an array.

Here is my code:

```
migration.enumerateObjects(Word.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
    var defString = oldObject["string"] as String
    var defArray: [String] = defString.componentsSeparatedByString("/")
    println(defArray) // [variant of 籲|吁[yu4]]
    newObject["array"] = defArray
}
```

When I run the migration it displays this error: `'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid value for property'`

Here is the string that is throwing the exception: `/variant of 籲|吁[yu4]/`

I have tried removing the brackets and the pipe, but it still doesn't work. I am not sure if it is because of this particular string or if it has to do with some sort of incorrect type.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm doesn't support storing properties of Swift's `Array` type. Realm *does* support `RLMArray` properties, whose items must instances of an `RLMObject` subclass.

See Realm's documentation on [Models](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/latest/#models) or on [RLMArrays](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.88.0/api/Classes/RLMArray.html) for more information.